# MySQL problems with ALL operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project and I need to get some data from database. 
First of all I have activities and they depend on a day of a planification. I want to award users who have done the activities the first week, for exemple.

In order to get the activities of the first week I'm doing this SQL:

```
SELECT activitat
FROM planning_activitats
WHERE (activitat <> 'CTS' AND activitat <> 'TRU' AND activitat <> 'Test')
  AND dia >= 1 AND dia <= 7
```

This query is correct and I get all the activities in a correct way. Ok, now I want to know what users have done these activities and I do this SQL:

```
SELECT user
FROM activitats_completades
WHERE activitat = ALL ($sql)
  AND user NOT IN (SELECT user FROM puntuacions_setmanals WHERE setmana = 1)
```

Where `$sql` is the first SQL. The second part of `WHERE (AND user NOT IN...)` is because I need to manage what users have been awarded and they can't be awarded another time.

I think the problem is in `ALL` operator because I'm doing the query and I'm getting 0 results. What I'm doing bad? I have checked database and data is correct and it should give me some user because I have users who have done all the activities.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Data samples -> User "user" have done activities "ACT1, ACT2, ACT3", "user2" have done "ACT1, ACT4" and this week activities are "ACT1, ACT4". In this case, "user2" should be the result.

Comment: One value cannot be equal to all of several different values. For illustration - try to find a number which is `= ALL (3, 5, 7)`. Did you mean `WHERE activitat IN ($sql)`?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @Amadan in the first query I get, for example, ACT1, ACT2 and ACT3. And I want to get users that have done the 3 activities, how can I do it? I understand you, but how can I solve it? I'm using PHP but i prefer not to work with arrays, but if it's the solution... Is possible to solve it with SQL queries?

Comment: I don't want to try to start making queries since you haven't provided the schema; but if you want to make sure a user has done 3 activities, you need to COUNT results of a subquery or group and make sure he has the requisite number.

Comment: @Amadan yes but it's not the solution because I need to check the name of activities, not the number of them becasue the number always will be the same (5 activities for week)

Comment: Check them inside the query that you are counting. `COUNT(SELECT activity blah blah WHERE name IN ('ACT1', 'ACT4')) = 2`.

Comment: So it's an array treatment. I'll do with this method but I would prefer to do it with a simple query. Thanks @Amadan

Comment: What array treatment? It's all in SQL. If you have a table with weekly activities, you don't even hardcode the values. Which just goes to show - whenever you are asking about SQL, _post the schema_. (Preferably in SQL form: `CREATE TABLE...`)

Comment: Do you need the activitat = ALL if you need all the users just remove that condition.. or i think your query is not very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ac.user
FROM activitats_completades ac
WHERE ac.activitat IN (SELECT pa.activitat
                       FROM planning_activitats pa
                       WHERE pa.activitat NOT IN ('CTS', 'TRU', 'Test') AND
                             pa.dia >= 1 AND pa.dia <= 7
                      ) AND
     ac.user NOT IN (SELECT ps.user FROM puntuacions_setmanals WHERE ps.setmana = 1);
```

There is no need to save the returned values in a variable.

To get users that match all the activities, use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT ac.user
FROM activitats_completades ac
WHERE ac.activitat IN (SELECT pa.activitat
                       FROM planning_activitats pa
                       WHERE pa.activitat NOT IN ('CTS', 'TRU', 'Test') AND
                             pa.dia >= 1 AND pa.dia <= 7
                      ) AND
     ac.user NOT IN (SELECT ps.user FROM puntuacions_setmanals WHERE ps.setmana = 1)
GROUP BY ac.user
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM planning_activitats pa
                   WHERE pa.activitat NOT IN ('CTS', 'TRU', 'Test')
                  );
```

This assumes that each table does not have duplicates.  You might need `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that should solve your problem. It is what I spoke of before, but in pretty and usable:

```
SELECT user
FROM activitats_completades
WHERE activitat IN (
    SELECT activitat
    FROM planning_activitats
    WHERE (activitat <> 'CTS' AND activitat <> 'TRU' AND activitat <> 'Test')
    AND dia >= 1 AND dia <= 7
)
AND user NOT IN (SELECT user FROM puntuacions_setmanals WHERE setmana = 1)
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(activitat) = (
    SELECT COUNT(activitat)
    FROM planning_activitats
    WHERE (activitat <> 'CTS' AND activitat <> 'TRU' AND activitat <> 'Test')
    AND dia >= 1 AND dia <= 7
)
```

Comment: @msabate [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39795c/7/0) you will find users 0 and 1 who made both "foo" and "bar" activities and user 3 who just made "foo". The rest did none of them. As the result of the query you find just users 0 and 1.

Comment: @msabate Now I saw the mistake... I did not remove the ALL operator when copying your query.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IN operator, since you want to compare each "activitat" to each result from your SQL query. Just make sure not to return multiple columns in the ($sql) query.

```
SELECT user 
FROM activitats_completades 
WHERE activitat IN
    ($sql)
AND user NOT IN 
    (SELECT user 
     FROM puntuacions_setmanals 
     WHERE setmana=1)
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to get users that have done all the activities of the query, not one of them.

Comment: @msabate I would play with comparing the amount then: ... GROUP BY user HAVING COUNT(activitat) = \*Amount of activities\*. The amount of activities can be read with another sql statement.

Comment: It works for m, it's the same as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the IN operator for activitat  column and using between for  dia column :

SELECT activitat
FROM planning_activitats
WHERE activitat NOT IN ('CTS','TRU','Test') AND dia between 1 AND 7;